# Is there a way to determine how POCO properties are serialized with YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

If I have a POCO defined in C#, can I control how the properties of that POCO are represented in YAML?

For example:

```
class A
{
      string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I would like it to be serialized as below (lower case, essentially):

```
a:
 name: value
```

In json.net I can decorate the POCO using attributes that determine how that object should be serialized. Is there an equivalent in YamlDotNet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the [naming convention](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/tree/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/NamingConventions) that will be used by the serializer and deserialiser. You can also [decorate your members](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/YamlAliasAttribute.cs) with `[YamlAlias("name")]` to alter the name of a particular member.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! thank you @antoineaubry. i sent you an email, feel free to ignore it :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using `YamlMember` (e.g. `[YamlMember(Alias = "name")]`).

`YamlMember` can also be used to control the order of items as they're serialised.